# How to pass data from parent component to children but from children prop ( like Formik)

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I will try to explain what I want. Trying to make something like Formik.
I want something like this:

```
<Parent>
{(someData)=>(
  <>
   {console.log(someData)}
  </>
)}
</Parent>
```

Parent component have `children` prop. How to pass this `someData` from Parent component?

Parent component is:

```
const Parent =({children})=>{
const value='Pass to children';

  return ({children})
}
```

How to pass this `value` through children porp?

Like on this link:https://formik.org/docs/guides/react-native

Comment: Were you able to find how to do it? i want to do the same.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you are trying to achieve but I do think I can help!

In react we can either pass props down to children components or we can use the useCallback hook function to pass data back to the parent, I'll show you what I mean.

As you can see in this parent element we can declare our properties which we would like to pass to our child. In this case we are passing a string with the variable name props. and a function with the variable name callLogger.

```
 const Parent = () => {

    const loggerFunction = (argument) => {
       console.log(argument)
    })

    return (
      <Child props={'hello world'} callLogger={loggerFunction}/>
   )
}
```

We can then use these values inside of our child component like so. In this example props holds a value of 'hello world'. When we use the useCallback hook, we pass in an argument, 'props'. Which is then passed back to parent component where it is called by the function we have passed in.

```
 const Child = ({props, callLogger}) => {

    const logger = useCallback((argument) => {
       callLogger(argument);
    })

    return (
      <div onClick={e => {e.preventDefault(); logger(props)}/>
   )
}
```

It may also be worth noting that in order to use this child component anywhere else you will still have to pass it the required properties in order for it to work. Hence why it is is safest to plan which components will require this data and find the best suited parents component to handle all of the logic of the two containers.

Comment: I typed this in  stack overflow directly so this code may include bugs

Comment: This is not an answer that I'm looking for :/ I know how to pass props or functions to child like you wrote.

Comment: Are you trying to pass props though child components? As in to pass props from App.js to Header.js and then to nav.js so that the nav component has this prop?

Comment: Literally I'm trying to achieve like Formik. Formik exposes "values, SetFields, ResetForm..."

Comment: Build forms in React, without the tears. This one?

Comment: https://formik.org/docs/guides/react-native this one

Answer (score 0):

I think you are talking about **render props**

```
const Parent = ({children}) =>{
   const value='Pass to children';

   return children(value)
}
```

you have to call `children` as function.

and you use it like this:

```
<Parent>
   {(someData)=>(
     <>
      {someData}
     </>
   )}
</Parent>
```

or like this:

```
<Parent children={(someData) => <>{someData}</>} />
```

Comment: This is not what I'm looking for

Comment: This is how you pass value through children prop. children is a function, you call it and pass arguments whatever you want, and then return it to render. This works exactly like formik. Formik passes an object, you can pass an object too. İf this is not what are you looking for, can you explain clearly what exactly you want